# Schedule node modifications?

Tags: nodes, rules

I use Scheduler when i need to public/unpublish nodes and it works pretty well, but i would like to  schedule the modification of an specific node? is there any module or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "schedule the modification of a node"? Is it like "publish a new revision of the node"? If so, where would such revision come from (be stored before it is published)? Or is it something completely different? Please EDIT your question to clarify this.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this question a bit further please? I've a possible answer in mind, but will only post it if I'm sure it makes sense (and applies). I don't want to post answers that are like "guesses", ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Workbench Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_scheduler). you could make changes as a draft(or any other workbench moderation state) and let Scheduler publish it.